# General questions regarding CALs and WS 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, licensing, cal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a few questions regarding CALs and Windows Server 2003:

1 - what happens if you join more computers to the domain than available CALs, do some computers get disconnected from the domain?
2 - Under **Administration Tools -> Licensing**, what does the **Maximum usage** field stand for?
3 - In case answer to question 2 is  *"The maximum number of licenses used of all time"* what could explain the fact that we are currently using more computers than the Maximum usage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows CAL licensing is done on trust, so if you have more connected devices/users than you have CAL's for then nothing will happen to them, but you will be in breach of your licence.

The Maximum usage field indicates the maximum amount of concurrent users you have had connected at the same time. This is the highest it has got to, at a single point, it is not cumulative. Depending on whether you are licensing your CALs on a per user or per device usage, it may indicate that you need more CALs.

Comment: Almost perfect answer (using the same number references would help the review). Couldn't vote up due to low reputation but definitely worth one. Thanks.